# Get Random points inside custom shape

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Im creating a game and require monsters to spawn in a specific area. I have created Nodes that connect to each other to outline where a monster can spawn. I do this by checking the maximum X axis, Y and Z of each node. However, this leaves me with a square which i dont want. how do i extrude out the shape from the square i need.

here is a picture of what i need, the values are just examples.

[image: Area Example]

Please keep in mind that the shape can have any number of nodes.

after a bit of researching, i found that convex hulls omit the the points that are on the inside. I want every point to be included in the calculated. [Here you can see what a Convex Hull would do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf6zc.png)

Comment: What you want is called the convex hull of your points. There are several algorithms, a google search should give you useful results.

Comment: thank you il have a look

Comment: @Arthur i had a look at some Convex algorithms, mostly the Gift wrap. And it is not what i need please see the edit.

Comment: Then there isn't a unique way to do it. How will you decide which way is the _right_ way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out my own method to do it. I basically Take two nodes at random and get the distance between them. I than get a random float between 1 and 0 that decides how far into the distance the new position should be. From this new position i take a new random node and repeat the same thing. I do this about 3 times at which point i take the last position that has been chosen.

The result is a nice even distribution of random positions all inside the custom shape which looks like this: [All of the grey dots are randomly placed objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5STFw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the convex hull of the red points:

[image]

Comment: what if you wanted it to include all the points when creating the boundry? I am asking this because a node may be placed far inside due to an obstacle such as a mountain that is on the side. With your example that node will be ignored and the boundry will go through the mountain.

Comment: @Prime:  Are you allowing your boundary to be non-convex?  If so, then all you can do is "connect the dots" and color in the enclosed region.  If that is the case, you should really re-write your question (which should otherwise be avoided, whenever possible, as it annoys potential helpers).

Comment: ... and what does "square" have to do with your question?

Comment: I apologize my title was misleading.